# .htaccess link with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a page with URL like this:
https://something.com/paste/log.php?log=H7nSEIPaVr

(By the way my homepage is:
https://something.com/paste/index.php
)

I want to make it work by just giving the log parameter like this:
https://something.com/paste/H7nSEIPaVr
And it would redirect me to the original url.
(or it would be better if it just give me the paramter - ?log=xxx)

I have a .htaccess file, but it is not working for me.
(rewrite is enabled, so the htaccess is working well)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /paste/^([a-zA-Z0-9]*$)/?     /log.php?log=$1    [QSA]
```

Comment: Please share the .htaccess file then

Comment: I just have the "RewriteEngine On" inside the .htaccess right now.

Comment: Look into PHP routing. You write a simple htaccess rule that routes all missing files/folders to a single PHP file, and from there you do whatever you want such as include, redirect, etc. This is how pretty much every modern CMS works. Today you are routing the paste URL, but tomorrow you might want another, and this allows you to do it all in PHP with no future changes to htaccess.

Comment: Right now i have

"RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /paste/^([a-zA-Z0-9]*$)/?     /log.php?log=$1    [QSA]"

inside my htaccess file, but it still doenst working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is the rule you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?paste/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /paste/log.php?log=$1 [L]
```

That rule needs to be implemented in the central http server's host configuration. Or, if you do not have access to that, you can instead use a *distributed* configuration file (typically called ".htaccess") which has to be located inside the http server's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

An alternative would be to place that variant in a distributed file inside the `/paste` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ log.php?log=$1 [L]
```